# problem with code page

Tags: c#, winforms

i need to read text hebrew file `(ANSI)` - i try to save as `Unicode` or `UTF-8`

and i see only `?????` or  `_+_+_+#@#@#@`

i try this:

```
FS = new FileStream(FilePath , FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite);
SW = new StreamReader(FS,Encoding.Default);
```

how to read with `CodePage='1255'` ? or how to solve this ?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

Pass `new Encoding(1255)`. (Untested but according to documentation should work).

Answer (score 0):

I think this line:

```
SW = new StreamReader(FS,Encoding.Default);
```

needs to be this:

```
SW = new StreamReader(FS,Encoding.ASCIIEncoding);
```

If that doesn't work your problem is almost certainly to do with the Encoding option you've set.

Comment: That's not likely to get it done. You'd need to specify 1255 code page somewhere.